# Update List element at specified list item position

Tags: c#

I am trying to do this:

```
foreach (Settings sets in MySets)
            {
                if (sets.pName == item.SubItems[2].Text)
                {
                    var ss = new SettingsForm(sets);
                    if (ss.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        if (ss.ResultSave)
                        {
                            sets = ss.getSettings();
                        }
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
```

But since the sets spawned variable is readonly, I cant override it.

I would also like to do something like this

```
foreach (Settings sets in MySets)
{

  if(sets.pName == someName)
     sets.RemoveFromList();
}
```

How can I accomplish this? Lists have a very nice Add() method, but they forgot the rest :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
MySets.RemoveAll(sets => sets.pName == someName);
```

to remove all the items that satisfy a specific condition.

If you want to grab all the items satisfying a condition without touching the original list, you can try:

```
List<Settings> selectedItems = MySets.FindAll(sets => sets.pName == someName);
```

`foreach` loops don't work here as trying to change the underlying list will cause an exception in the next iteration of the loop. Of course, you can use a `for` loop and manually index the list. However, you should be very careful not to miss any items in the process of removing an item from the list (since the index of all the following items will get decremented if an element is removed):

```
for (int i = 0; i < MySets.Count; ++i) {
   var sets = MySets[i]; // simulate `foreach` current variable

   // The rest of the code will be pretty much unchanged.
   // Now, you can set `MySets[i]` to a new object if you wish so:
   //   MySets[i] = new Settings(); 
   //
   // If you need to remove the item from a list and need to continue processing
   // the next item:   (decrementing the index var is important here)
   //   MySets.RemoveAt(i--);
   //   continue;

   if (sets.pName == item.SubItems[2].Text)
   {
      var ss = new SettingsForm(sets);
      if (ss.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         if (ss.ResultSave)
         {
            // Assigning to `sets` is not useful. Directly modify the list:
            MySets[i] = ss.getSettings();
         }
      }
      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 

But how do I update an existing list.. something like :

update setting x where x.name = "john" with setting y

And that setting X is inside a list ... of course

Comment: @SilentWarrior: If `Setting` is a reference type, you can already change its *members* with the `foreach` loop construct. If you need to change the reference itself or if it's a value type, you'll need to resort to an indexed `for` loop. Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Isnt there any prettier way of doing it?

Anyways thx for all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a 'regular' for loop?

Comment: I want to drop the for loop altogether, not pretty